# name 'Text' is not defined in HSTORE Sqlalchemy migration

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

When I try to add HSTORE to my model and try to upgrade head it throws me `NameError: name 'Text' is not defined`.

I used `PYTHONPATH=. alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Added user_id, admin_id and role to Customer"` to create the revision.

Thanks in advance?

**Update:**
@Daniel Roseman suggested me to add `sa.Text()`. My question is why it has not been generated automatically during revision

Error:

> op.add_column('customers', sa.Column('user_id',
>   postgresql.HSTORE(text_type=Text()), nullable=True)) NameError: name
>   'Text' is not defined

Model:

```
class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "customers"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    img = Column(String, nullable=False)
    auth_token = Column(String, nullable=True)
    notification_config = Column(JSONB, nullable=True)
    admin_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    user_id = Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(HSTORE))
```

Generated Migration revision:

```
"""Added user_id, admin_id and role to Customer

Revision ID: 1ebe3d18442f
Revises: 88b4dccb5c1e
Create Date: 2017-06-21 17:03:21.181933

"""

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '1ebe3d18442f'
down_revision = '88b4dccb5c1e'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.add_column('customers', sa.Column('admin_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=True))
    op.add_column('customers', sa.Column('auth_token', sa.String(), nullable=True))
    op.add_column('customers', sa.Column('user_id', postgresql.HSTORE(text_type=Text()), nullable=True))
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_column('customers', 'user_id')
    op.drop_column('customers', 'auth_token')
    op.drop_column('customers', 'admin_id')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error? It's telling you that you haven't defined `Text` before calling it. And, it's clear from the code that indeed you haven't defined it. Where is supposed to be coming from? Do you perhaps mean `sa.Text()`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Why it is not generated automatically. I used `PYTHONPATH=. alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Added user_id, admin_id and role to Customer"
`

Comment: The migration generation process is not perfect. It even says `commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust!`.